# Python con permisos de administrador

Tags: python, windows, cmd

estoy intentando crear reglas del firewall con python, para esto estoy usando "subprocess" pero al momento de ingresar el comando se requiere elevación. He visto que se puede usar el comando "runas" pero no me queda muy claro como exactamente aplicarlo al programa.
¿Como podría darle permisos de administrador al programa? o ¿cómo podría ingresar el comando desde un cmd que no tenga los permisos?

La línea de código es la siguiente

```
subprocess.run('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="cerrar80" protocol=tcp dir=out localport=80 action=block enable=yes', shell=True)
```

Comment: No creo que el programa pueda darse una elevacion a si mismo. Eso seria un pinche de seguridad grave, pues un virus tambien podria darse elevacion a si mismo. Supongo que a lo que te refieres es "como puedo hacer que mi programa pida permisos de administrador?"

Comment: Si, lo que busco es la manera en la que el comando se pueda ejecutar, no necesariamente solo. Los permisos los podría otorgar el usuario.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sirve en el futuro, para solucionarlo convertí el archivo .py en un ejecutable .exe y lo ejecute como administrador. Facilito.